# how to customize the alert of browser close window using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to customize the browser alert box text when we click on browser close ('x') button of respective tab. I tried with `window.onbeforeunload` but it's not working for me.

Can any one help me using angular?

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as this:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('exitController', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.onExit = function() {
      return ('leaving page');
    };

   $window.onbeforeunload =  $scope.onExit;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="exitController">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">Leave page</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to change the text of  "do you leave the page" alert text.

Comment: i tried above code already it won't work for me

Comment: i need to modify the browser default alert text when we click on browser "x" icon